# How to run multiple ssh sessions from a remote server

Tags: azure, ssh, ubuntu-16.04

I have deployed a topology of VMs in a VNET on Azure. There is one jumpbox which has access to all these machines and is part of VNET. There are some 25 machines which this jumpbox provides access to.

I want to be able to simultaneously run commands and scripts on all the VMs through this jumpbox.

I installed cssh and it shows following error:

> Can't find DISPLAY -- guessing unix:0' at /usr/share/perl5/App/ClusterSSH.pm line 1981.
>
> Can't connect to display unix:0': No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/X11/Protocol.pm line 2264.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76777

In essence:

1. Setup Public Key authentication between the jumpbox and your servers.
2. `for host in $(cat hosts.txt); do ssh "$host" "$command" > "output.$host" ; done`

`pssh` is probably the better tool for this job:
https://www.linux.com/news/parallel-ssh-execution-and-single-shell-control-them-all

`cssh` should also work, just don't do X11 stuff with it or make sure you have X11 forwarding enabled. Actually, i'm lying, i have no idea if it works without xterm.